# References on the non-decomponition of linear correlations

Tags: correlation, linear

Given $a, b, c, d$ as numeric vectors of the same lenght (e.g. 2), and $\phi$ being a measure of linear correlation (e.g. Yule-Pearson correlation = Matthews Correlation Coefficient),

I would like academic references on this inequality:

$l[\phi(a,b),\phi(c,d)] \neq \phi[l(a,c),l(b,d)]$

where $l$ is any linear function (linear map?).

Comment: This seems fairly uncommon; why do you need this? It may help guide the literature search you're outsourcing.

Comment: Imagine that I want to random samples multivariate observations; would the correlations within the sample be representative of the correlations of the population with the same "strenght" (I don't think that margin of error is appropriate here) of the of the unbiased estimator for locations of the same variables, disjointed, with the same sample size?